# Adding Scripts in the Admin Area

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script

I'd like to enqueue scripts only for an admin page that I've created.

There's an example of this here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_scripts_only_on_plugin_pages

But it's not working for me, I think because I'm writing my plugin within a class.  add_action only works with in the constructor??

Is there a way to add scripts to a specific page from within a class?

I came up with this method:
My main plugin page is a list of custom post types (if you set `'show_in_menu' => 'custom_page_slug'` in the post type args it takes over that page with a list of posts).  When I created the post type, I set a variable up with the post type name:

```
$args = register_post_type('post-type', $args );
$this->posttype = $args->name;
```

Then this call in the constructor:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', array( &$this, 'scripts_init' ) );
```

And this in the `scripts_init` function:

```
global $current_screen;    
if( $current_screen->id == $this->posttype )
{
wp_enqueue_script( ... );
}
```

It works.  But it seems more complicated than it needs to be.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of hooking into `admin_print_scripts` **only**, you should hook into your specific page slug which is appended to `admin_print_scripts-`.  (note trailing hyphen).  The reference page you linked to shows this, but you seem to be omitting the `$page` concatenation to `admin_print_scripts-`.

eg:

```
$page = add_theme_page( 'Options', 'Options', 'edit_theme_options', 'options-panel', 'topf_admin_options_markup' );

add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$page", 'enqueue_my_admin_scripts' );
```

I'm using the slug `$page` returned from `add_theme_page;` you should provide your own slug.  Scripts will only be loaded for your specific page and there is no need to check within your enqueue function.

Comment: That's not working.  The add_action has to be within the __construct to work.  Even if I set up a class variable then try to access it: add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-'.$this->pagename, 'scripts_init' ), it doesn't work.  Its like the variable is not set yet.  Maybe it has something to do with the order in which the action hooks fire?

Comment: The add_action does not have to be in the __construct.  It should be where ever you are creating your page. 

eg:

`class ControlPanel
{
 function __construct()
 {
  add_action( 'admin_menu', array( &$this , 'my_admin_menu' ));
 }

 function my_admin_menu()
 {
  $page = add_theme_page('DTI Options', 'DTI Options', 'edit_theme_options', "diverge_theme_options", array( &$this , 'optionspage' ));
  add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$page", array( &$this , 'scripts_init' ));
 }
}`